# Swift Multiplayer Game Losing Access to previous version game

Tags: swift, app-store, game-center, multiplayer

I submitted my multiplayer app version 1.0 that worked great. I then found a small bug to do with the sounds that was easy to fix, so I did so and submitted version 1.1. The problem is that players that update to version 1.1 cannot access the multiplayer games that they started in 1.0 anymore. I'm looking at the Multiplayer Compatibility Section on the App Store connect website and it says the earliest compatible version is 1.0, so I'm not sure why this happened. I then fixed another bug 2 weeks later and made sure to select 1.0 as the earliest compatible version, but now players cannot access their games started in 1.0 or 1.1.

When I released 1.2 through TestFlight my testers were able to access their 1.0 and 1.1 games from 1.2, but not the live version.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!